# $\vert zf(z)-1+e^z \vert \leq 1 + \vert z\vert$ for the Entire funtion $f(z)$. Find the Value of $\int_{\vert z \vert=1}\frac{(z+1)f(z)}{z^3}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

A Entire funtion $f(z)$ satisfying $\vert zf(z)-1+e^z \vert \leq 1 + \vert z\vert$. Find the Value of $\int_{\vert z \vert=1}\frac{(z+1)f(z)}{z^3}dz$

Let me show my solution.
I found the form of the $f(z) =a+\frac{1-e^z}{z}$ for the complex constant, $a$. The reason why I conclude like that is $g(z) = az$ by Liouville's theorem and $g(0)=0$ (Here $g(z) =zf(z)-1+e^z$ )

Say $h(z) = \frac{(z+1)f(z)}{z^3} = \frac{(z+1)}{z^3}(a+\frac{1-e^z}{z})$. From this, I tried to apply the residue theorem. So I tried to find the for laurent series. In my thought it is enough to only consider the $\frac{-ze^z-e^z}{z^4}$ for finding the coefficient of $z^{-1}$.

From the Maclaurine series of the $e^z$, $res(h,0) = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}  = -\frac{5}{6}$

So final answer is $-\frac{5}{3}\pi i$. But the answer sheet claimed the answer is $-\frac{4}{3}\pi i$. What the point did I wrong?

Regards

Comment: Liouville's Theorem does not tell you that $g$ is a constant. It tells you that $g(z)=az+b$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, Yes it does. So I used the condition $g(0)=0$. So we can conclude $g(z)=az$

Comment: @geetha290krm, Ah that was typo. My intent was $g(z) =az$ not $g= a$

Comment: You have erred in calculation of the residue.

Comment: @geetha290krm, Oh yeah I just found my mistakes. I should modify $-1/3$ to $-1/6$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-\frac {4\pi i} 3$ is the correct answer. $g$ is not bounded and we can only say that $g(z)$ has the form $az+b$. Since $g(0)=0$ we get $g(z)=bz$. Now $f(z)=b   +\frac  {1-e^{z}} z$.  For this function the Residue Theorem gives the answer as $-\frac {4\pi i} 3$. Note that the integral of $\frac {1+z} {z^{3}}$ is $0$ since this function has  an analytic anti-derivative.

The residue is $-\frac 1 2 -\frac 1 {3!}$ and not $-\frac 1 2 -\frac 1 {3}$.